# How can I add default scope / conditions on a relationship in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations

So I have a table called `files` which contains a list of files with their respective name, path and file-type. Then I have a few other tables, to which files can be attached. For example the table `user_profiles`. And finally I have a pivot table for the Many To Many Polymorphic relationship between files and other tables. The pivot table is called `fileables` (couldn't think of a better name). Now users may have a few images attached to their profile and maybe a few videos, which both come from files.

Normally, if it were only images, I would do something like this:

```
class UserProfile extends Model {

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\File', 'fileable');
    }

}
```

However, since it's images and videos, I'd like to do something like this:

```
class UserProfile extends Model {

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\File', 'fileable')->where('type', 'LIKE', 'image%');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\File', 'fileable')->where('type', 'LIKE', 'video%');
    }

}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. So what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: "that doesn't seem to work" is not very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create scopes on your `File` model:

```
public function scopeImages($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', 'LIKE', 'image/%');
}

public function scopeVideos($query)
{
    return $query->where('type', 'LIKE', 'video/%');
}
```

And then use those in your `UserProfile` model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\File', 'fileable')->images();
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\File', 'fileable')->videos();
}
```

Comment: Actually, I found out my code did work. I just had a typo in it. But your code is much cleaner. :-)